# Rails check box in form decides on create action in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, controller

I am trying to add a select box to the base of my create form that decides if an action runs from the controller...if that makes any sense?

Basically the application creates a project in FreeagentCentral whenever a new project is made:

```
def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:kase][:company_id])
    @kase = @company.kases.create!(params[:kase])
    
    respond_to do |format|
        params[:send_to_freeagent] ? @kase.create_freeagent_project(current_user)
        
        #flash[:notice] = 'Case was successfully created.'
        flash[:notice] = fading_flash_message("Case was successfully created.", 5)
        
        format.html { redirect_to(@kase) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @kase, :status => :created, :location => @kase }
    end
  end
```

and within my form I have:

```
<%= check_box_tag :send_to_freeagent, 1 %> Create project in Freeagent?
```

What I would like to happen, is if the select box is checked the project is sent to Freeagent. If not, the case just gets created locally as normal but without the Freeagent data being sent.

If I use the above code, I get an exception caught error:

```
SyntaxError in KasesController#new
controllers/kases_controller.rb:114: syntax error, unexpected '\n'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you have on line 114?

Comment: 114.         params[:send_to_freeagent] ? @kase.create_freeagent_project(current_user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
def create
   @company = Company.find(params[:kase][:company_id])
   @kase = @company.kases.create!(params[:kase])

   @kase.create_freeagent_project(current_user) if params[:send_to_freeagent].to_bool

   respond_to do |format|       
      # ...
   end
end
```

Comment: `params[:send_to_freeagent].to_bool` will throw an exception unless the check box is checked, because unchecked boxes are not submitted at all.  You can just check `params[:send_to_freeagent]`; any value at all indicates the box is checked.